# Ubuntu 22.04.04 - Dell XPS 13 9310 doesn't suspends on lid close

Tags: server, grub2, gnome, dell, power-management

It was working perfectly but after reinstalling my GUI, the lid is closed the screen turns off but doesn't suspend properly.

I noticed that the laptop is hot and the battery is draining when taking it out of the travel case.

I've tried uncommenting these lines in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

```
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

and rebooted but didn't make any difference.

I also tried replacing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep"` in file /etc/default/grub but that didn't work as well.

The S3 deep sleep mode is not available on the XPS 13 9310.
https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-13-9310-Ubuntu-deep-sleep-missing/td-p/7734008

Comment: Same laptop, same problem.

Comment: @ThomasSpeidel Are you using Linux OS or Windows?

Comment: yes, Pop_OS! I just installed Fedora and the same problem occurs.  This started happening about 6 months ago, so I feel it may have been a kernel update at that time.

Comment: Yeah, I also tried installing different Linux desktop environments but the problem still exists.

Comment: @ThomasSpeidel It was indeed because of the Kernel update.
Reverting back to 5.15.0.60 from 5.19.0.32 resolves this issue immediately.

Answer (score 1):

After 22.04 LTS upgraded the linux-generic-hwe kernel to 5.19.0.32 (from 5.15.0.60) suspend/wake up is broken.
The system refuses to wake up in about 50% of the cases, seemingly random. The only "solution" is a forced system power down.
Reverting back to 5.15.0.60 resolves this issue immediately.